# Query consistently successful?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making a successful unsuccessful message, but when I add control, it always returns successfully?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO iletisim(Mesaj,Gonderen,Mail,Konu,Durum) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
$this->db->query($sql, array(
    $this->db->escape_str($mesaj),
    $this->db->escape_str($name),
    $this->db->escape_str($mail),
    $this->db->escape_str($konu),
    "0")
);
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_success', 'Success.');
    return redirect(base_url("iletisim/succes"));
}
else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_error', 'Error');
    return redirect(base_url("iletisim/error"));
}
```

Comment: affected rows correlates to updates, insert id is the one you should be using

Comment: and using `->escape_str` is redundant, you're binding it already, those are escaped automatically

Answer (score 0):

If `insert` query executed successfully then it always returns `1` (TRUE). You can use this to detect your result.

For example :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO iletisim(Mesaj,Gonderen,Mail,Konu,Durum) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
$result = $this->db->query($sql, array($this->db->escape_str($mesaj),$this->db->escape_str($name),$this->db->escape_str($mail),$this->db->escape_str($konu),"0"));
if(!empty($result)) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_success', 'Success.');
    redirect("iletisim/succes");
}
else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_error', 'Error');
    redirect("iletisim/error");
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it is impossible to `return` the value of `redirect()` because `redirect()` does not return anything, or more precisely, it does not return. The last line of code in it is `exit;` which causes script execution to end immediately.

Comment: The 'msg_error' and `redirect("iletisim/error")` code lines do not need to be in an `else{}` block because the `if(){ ... }` block ends script execution. In other words, if `$result` is `false` then the next line of code that runs will be the one after the `if(){ ... }` block.

Comment: You don't need to use `base_url` as part of the argument to `redirect`, i.e. `redirect(base_url("iletisim/error"));` because `redirect` will do that for you.

Comment: Sorry @DFriend, I Forgot to check remaining statements of the code. Thanks for informing, You taught me a lesson.

Comment: @DFriend, I am unable to understand why `else` block is not needed?

Comment: Alok, If the conditional `if(!empty($result))` is true then the next two lines of code will execute. The second line `redirect("iletisim/succes");` **will** end script execution. Therefore, no code outside the closing brace of `if(!empty($result))` will execute. Obviously then if ``if(!empty($result))` is false code execution will begin **after** the closing brace. I hope this helps you see how the call to `redirect` elminiates the need for the `else`.

Comment: @DFriend, what will happen when an error occurs to insert. It will stop execution and will not redirect to `redirect("iletisim/error");`

Comment: Yes, if execution stops then no code is executed because... well, execution has stopped.

Comment: Because $result is a boolean I suggest that this - if(!empty($result)) be changed to `if($result)` or  `if($result !== false)`